# Speed up Frontrun Bot

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions, blocks, bot

I've made a frontrun bot for the Binance Smart Chain.
It's working fine, but just for 50% of all transactions..

In the other 50% the is missing the transaction by 1 block.. Example is below
My question is: How can I be 100% sure, that my transaction will get into the same block?

**Example**
Transaction to attack:
Block: 16368965
Gwei: 5

[image: Transaction to attack]

My transaction:
Block: 16368966
Gwei: 6
[image: Bot transaction]

Comment: I'm currently working on making a frontrunning bot myself, if someone wants to work together on it, join my discord: discord.gg/XCX8V9X3M5

Answer (score 0):

Use Golang and don't skimp on gas.